# How to work with batch script dialog?

Tags: connection, batch, network-share, net-use

I am working on a batch script to remap a network drive in windows xp.  I have found it to work out well for the most part with:

```
net use G: /delete
net use G: \\file\share
```

However, if there are any connections to the drive, it will prompt:

> There are open files and/or incomplete directory searches pending on the connection to G:.
>
> Is it Ok to continue disconnecting and force them closed? (Y/N) [N]:

What would be the most graceful way of allowing for this dialog?  Is there ever a case where forcing a disconnect would lead to trauma?  Is there an alternative method of closing the connections, outside of deleting outright?  Kick everything off the drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there are actual files still being used on/from the mapped drive (shouldn't be if it's only being mapped to run a script, as long as the disconnect command is at the end) then there shouldn't be any problems forcing a disconnect. On the other hand, if there are files being read to/from the mapped drive, then you should expect some form of data loss.

I specify a force disconnect in my batch files by using:

> /delete /y

Answer (score 1):

This happens when files are still in use on the drive. I would strongly recommend closing *all* files and explorer windows that are open on the share before deleting it.

Forcing a disconnect with open files on the drive is akin to working on a file on the flash drive and then pulling it out while that file is still open. Data corruption galore.

Comment: This is one of those super paranoid questions, but I am guessing that these are all connections between the local machine and the network drive, and not any other sort of connections.  I.E. I am not messing with anyone else by ending my relationship with the drive.

Comment: @MattUebel - That's right. This will only hurt you, no one else.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when you have no open connections in use on the drive as well. Double check your scripts to see if the connection is ever opened.